# Importing functions in typescript

Tags: typescript

How can I reuse functions? I want to declare them once then include them in other files.

I created a module Global, containing some functions which I may want to add to other typescript files

I tried the following in another typescript file:

```
import test = require("./Global");
import * as testFunctions from "Global"
```

Both lines give errors saying the module cannot be found. The module is definitely visible to typescript as I am actually referencing this module at other places in the file, calling it's functions, which is working (EXAMPLE: Global.stopSpinner()).

Im not sure what I am doing wrong however, as I am following examples. Could someone explain me the correct way?

Answer (score 35):

An example:

```
// global.ts
export function abc() {
}

// main.ts
import { abc } from "./global"
abc();
```

I suggest to read [the introduction to ES6  modules from Mozilla](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/).

Comment: Thanks, I got it working now. It's not providing me with the expected functionality however. I though this way the function definition would be included in the created javascript. (Thus only have to include one file for the page and not also the js file which contains the referenced function).

Comment: @Kai If you use modules in a frontend application, then you have to use a bundler (Webpack) or a loader (SystemJS). Webpack is the easiest solution. [Here is a documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/webpack-and-typescript/).

Answer (score 4):

```js
//This is how it should look in order to work
import * as testFunctions from "./Global";
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

One option is simply to compile your library into a .js output file (and .d.ts typescript definitions file), and then include the .js file in your projects. You don't need to use a module system then, though it can be tricky getting your .js files in the right place and properly referenced and published.